# Unable to run shell script in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, sh

I am unable to make a script execute successfully from crontab.
When the script is executed manually, it works fine. When added to the crontab it gives errors.

When the script is executed manually as follows it all works fine:

```
cd /home/admin/git/Repo
./lunchpad2.sh
```

The script is added to crontab as follows:

```
sudo crontab -e
30 13 * * * /home/admin/git/Repo/lunchpad2.sh > /home/admin/git/Repo/outcome.err
```

lunchpad2.sh has 744 permissions set;

The script itself:

```
    #!/bin/bash -p
    PATH=$PATH:/home/admin/git/Repo

    echo "--> Starting!"

    echo "--> Stopping docker"
    docker-compose down

    echo "--> Switching files"
    mv dc_conf_standby.py dc_conf_aboutready.py 
    mv dc_conf.py dc_conf_standby.py 
    mv dc_conf_aboutready.py dc_conf.py 

    echo "--> Building docker"
    docker-compose up -d --build

    echo "--> Completed!"
```

The errors that are generated:

```
/home/admin/git/Repo/lunchpad2.sh: line 7: docker-compose: command not found
mv: cannot stat ‘dc_conf_standby.py’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘dc_conf.py’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘dc_conf_aboutready.py’: No such file or directory
/home/admin/git/Repo/lunchpad2.sh: line 15: docker-compose: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. You need to either cd in the script or in the cron job. Cron runs the command in your home directory. You can echo "$PWD" to confirm.
2. You need to specify docker-compose executable path (Run "which docker-compose" to confirm)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -p
   cd /home/admin/git/Repo

   echo "--> Starting!"

   echo "--> Stopping docker"
   /usr/bin/docker-compose down

   echo "--> Switching files"
   mv dc_conf_standby.py dc_conf_aboutready.py 
   mv dc_conf.py dc_conf_standby.py 
   mv dc_conf_aboutready.py dc_conf.py 

   echo "--> Building docker"
   /usr/bin/docker-compose up -d --build

   echo "--> Completed!"
   ```

Comment: which docker-compose returns "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", But the configuration file for the docker-compose build is within /home/admin/git/Repo/

Comment: Cron runs your commands in your home directory. You have to either cd in the script, or cd in the cron job "cd /home/admin/git/Repo && ./lunchpad2.sh > /home/admin/git/Repo/outcome.err"

Comment: I found out that the conf file can be passed as parameter - "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose/docker-compose -f /home/admin/git/Repo/docker-compose.yml down"

Comment: The errors it gives now are "/home/admin/git/Repo/lunchpad.sh: line 8: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose/docker-compose: Not a directory
/home/admin/git/Repo/lunchpad.sh: line 16: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose/docker-compose: Not a directory"

Comment: Why do you have /docker-compose/docker-compose? It gives "Not a directory" because the first layer of docker-compose is a executable.

Comment: Thank you for the help, managed to get arount which is where and which is what, final version is below:

`#!/bin/bash -p
PATH=$PATH:/home/admin/git/Repo
cd /home/admin/git/Repo
echo "--> Switching files"
mv "dc_conf_standby.py" "dc_conf_aboutready.py"
mv "dc_conf.py" "dc_conf_standby.py"
mv "dc_conf_aboutready.py" "dc_conf.py"

echo "--> Stopping docker"
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/admin/git/Repo/docker-compose.yml down

echo "--> Building docker"
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/admin/git/Repo/docker-compose.yml up -d --build

echo "--> Completed!"`